# Срабатывает часть кода в aiogram python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, telegram

Подскажите пожалуйста , почему код ниже может не срабатывать? В коде имеется тестовая функция start. Вот до нее почему то не доходит
для примера имеется такой код :

```
# Тут запускаю код в котором задается вопрос телеграм юзеру
async def mode(message : types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'введите цифру')


# Тут отлавливается первый ответ от тг юзера и задается второй вопрос
async def mode2(message : types.Message, state : FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['Первый'] = message.text
    await Ratio.next()
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'введите вторую цифру')


# Тут отлавливается второй ответ
async def mode3(message : types.Message, state : FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['Второй'] = message.text
    await state.finish()

# В зависимости от условия, выполняется разный код
if message.test == '1':
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Thanks')

else:
    # Функция старт, которое для примера создает тхт и записывает в него что-либо
    def start():
        with open(r'test.txt', 'w') as file:
            file.write(data['test_mode'])
    

def register_handlers_multi_mode(dp : Dispatcher):
    dp.register_message_handler(mode, commands=['test'], state = None)
    dp.register_message_handler(mode2, state = Ratio.test1)
    dp.register_message_handler(mode3, state = Ratio.test2)
```

Я понимаю что видимо упускаю какую-то мелочь, ну не могу понять какую.
В mode3, с помощью принта я выводил в консоль и первый ответ и второй ответ и все выводится, а значит работает. Но все работает до функции start

В оригинальном коде, в самой функции старт , выполняется много вычислений , в ходе которых создается xlsx файл, который должен отправляться в тг. За счет большого кода , сюда для примера скинул набросок с той же структурой, что и в оригинальном коде

Спасибо!

Comment: пример от разрабов https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram/blob/dev-2.x/examples/finite_state_machine_example.py

Comment: спасибо , я по этому примеру и отлавливаю ответы на вопросы в тг. Далее с этими ответами надо запустить функцию , в которой будет происходить генерация xlsx файла. В тг вопросы поступают , и ответы успешно отлавливаются, а вот сама функция не запускается. Основная функция не является handlers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может лучше так?

```
def start():
    with open(r'test.txt', 'w') as file:
        file.write(data['test_mode'])    

# Тут запускаю код в котором задается вопрос телеграм юзеру
async def mode(message : types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'введите цифру')


# Тут отлавливается первый ответ от тг юзера и задается второй вопрос
async def mode2(message : types.Message, state : FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['Первый'] = message.text
    await Ratio.next()
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'введите вторую цифру')


# Тут отлавливается второй ответ
async def mode3(message : types.Message, state : FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['Второй'] = message.text
    await state.finish()

    # В зависимости от условия, выполняется разный код
   if message.test == '1':
       await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Thanks')

   else:
       # Функция старт, которое для примера создает тхт и записывает в него что-либо
      start()
```

Comment: все равно не работает. просто код обходит функцию основную

Comment: @Stock, скопировал не глядя твой синтаксис) `if message.test == '1'` - ошибка, нет атрибута `test`, ты должен был указать `if message.text == '1':`

Comment: Ну и `message.text` будет работать только внутри функции получаемой этот самый `message`. Если ты хочешь сравнивать в одном условии и первое сообщение от пользователя и второе, то используй свой же словарь: `data['Второй']`

Comment: я test написал случайно ) так как код выше - это просто набросок. Основной оригинальный код , он большой очень. Сейчас пробую первый ваш вариант, сперва указываю основную функцию с основным кодом, после этого идут блоки, где отлавливаю ответы юзера. А после при ловле последнего ответа, я запускаю основную функцию и передаю ей переменные с ответами. ну теперь ошибка такая

    RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'multi' was never awaited
      multi(exchange, interval)
    RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

Comment: @Stock здесь уже речь о другой функции (“multi”?) и ожидании await

Comment: все тоже самое, просто название 'multi' из оригинального кода. Если сравнивать с кодом выше , то ошибка вот такая RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'start' was never awaited start(exchange, interval) RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

Comment: @Stock тогда у тебя два варианта: можешь отказаться от функции start и просто описать ее содержимое после else или сделал эту функцию асинхронной

Comment: Извините что надоедаю сильно. Скажите пожалуйста, а если я указал перед функцией 'async', то она уже считается ассинхронной? Выше , когда вы мне впервые ответили, я точно по такой же структуре переписал код, получается основная функция первым блоком идет , далее отлавливаю ответы и по окончанию в else вызываю саму основную функцию и передаю ей аргументы ( ответ ). но я получаю ошибку RuntimeWarning: coroutine...was never awaited ..... RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback. Я понял что за ошибка, ну не понял как устранить ее . Вы не подскажите?

Comment: все разобрался. спасибо большое вам. выполнил все как вы описали в первом вашем посте, в итоге после else запустил функцию и передал ей аргументы из ответов. далее в самой функции 'основной', у меня было условие if __name__ == '__main__' . Вот из за него код работал наполовину только. в итоге убрав if __name__ == '__main__' и запустив функцию внутри основной функции , все заработало. Обошлось без асинхронности кстати